# Filling closed shapes in XNA

Tags: c#, .net, math, curve

I need to render a 2D image in which the axises are latitude (φ) representing the X-axis and longitude (λ) for Y-axis. Assuming the viewpoint is always at the origin(0,0,0) then a 3D line segment in Cartesian coordinate is a 2D curve segment in this image. Here each point along the curve represents φ and λ angles. Having a 3D line segment from P1 to P2, and knowing the equation of the corresponding 2D curve segment, λ= f(φ), the curve can be drawn from φ1 to φ2. Three lines make a triangle. Therefore a triangle is drawn as three curve segments which makes a closed shape.

The problem is that this shape is drawn like in wire-frame mode and the enclosed area is not filled. I can't think of any way to somehow fill in the area. Is it possible to achieve this? I appreciate any help and like to discuses it with other.  Thanks

*Edit:

This cube has been drawn in Autocad:
[image]

The equation for a 3D line from P1(x1,y1,z1) to P2(x2,y2,z2) is:

```
(x-x1)/(x2-x1) = (y-y1)/(y2-y1) = (z-z1)/(z2-z1)
```

And This image(with latitude(φ) and longitude(λ) as axises) shows the same cube viewed from the origin:
[image]

The equation that gives λ along a 2D curved from φ1 to φ2(calculated from P1 and P2) is gained in this way:

```
λ= f(φ) = Atan((u/tan(φ)+z1)/ Sqrt((u/tan(φ)^2 + ((u/tan(φ))*w + y1)^2 ))
```

u and w are constants and are calculated thought P1 and P2 coordinates.

Here is the code for the above equation:

```
for (double tetha = φ1; tetha <= φ2; tetha += step){
double a = p1.X - p0.X;
double b = p1.Y - p0.Y;
double c = p1.Z - p0.Z;

double x = (a * p0.Y - b * p0.X) / (a * Math.Tan(tetha) - b);
double z = (((x - p0.X) * c) / a) + p0.Z;
double y = (((x - p0.X) * b) / a) + p0.Y;

if (a == 0)
{
y = (Math.Tan(tetha) * (b * p0.X - a * p0.Y)) / (b - a * Math.Tan(tetha));
z = (((y - p0.Y) * c) / b) + p0.Z;
x = (((y - p0.Y) * a) / b) + p0.X;
}

double landa = Math.Atan2(z, Math.Sqrt(x * x + y * y));
}
```

Comment: Where is the actual _XNA geometry_ code?

Comment: Sorry. I edited the tags. No XNA is involved.

Comment: If you are using XNA to render, you need to provide the code you are using to render the primitives.  i.e. GraphicsDevice.DrawPrimitives